# How to detect a string in all caps and convert it to start case

Tags: regex, string, r

Say I have the following vector

```
x <- c('One', 'TWO', 'THREE / FOUR')
```

I want to convert `TWO` and `THREE / FOUR` to `Two` and `Three / Four`, respectively. I've taken a look into `casefold()` and the whole `chartr()` help page but couldn't figure this out.

In my real problem, I have a vector of 1500 strings in which I intend to detect entries written in all caps (I know many of them include a slash just like the one in the example above) and convert them to start case.

One thing I can do is run `grepl('^[A-Z]+$', x)` (as suggested by tenub), but it doesn't detect the `THREE / FOUR` as being all caps (it yields `[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE`). From what I've seen, just the presence of a space is enough to have this return `FALSE`.

Removing the anchor `grepl('[A-Z]+$', x)` (as suggested by TheGreatCO) works for the example above, but fails in the next:

```
y <- "Imposto Territorial Rural - ITR"
grepl('[A-Z]+', y)
[1] TRUE
```

Moreover, elements containing accents are always left out, no matter what I try:

```
z <- c('Á')
grepl('[A-Z]+', z)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Well, `^[A-Z]+$` will capture all elements in your array that are *only* in all caps. You could then retrieve all but the first character and do a replace. I know in JavaScript you would simply do something like `array[i].substr(1)` to retrieve this part of each string. Maybe that can help you get started?

Comment: How do you define "regular case"? Is that CamelCase or Start Case or what?

Comment: @tenub, It does help get me started. I'll update the question with your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @TheGreatCO, I mean just the first letter being uppercase. What's the name for that? Sentence case, perhaps?

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio that would be Start Case.

Comment: In PHP there is `preg_match_all()` where you can retrieve all matches from a string. If you wanted to match `THREE / FOUR` I would change the RegEx to just `[A-Z]+` which would fill a matches array with all matches for each string. I don't know how versed you are in "r" but I know nothing about it unfortunately.

Comment: @tenub, I do well in R, but regex is still a mystery to me. Anyway, using `[A-Z]+` or any other combination I can think of just makes the whole vector `TRUE`.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio If you remove the anchor `^` it should detect both words as matches.

Comment: @TheGreatCO, you're right, it does (I got this result a second ago but failed to see `FALSE` in the first element). I think that does it. Let me just see if it works in the real data...

Comment: IF you really dislike regex, you could use `intToUtf8` and `utf8ToInt` to convert the string, check whether all numeric values are in the appropriate range for `A-Z`, and if so, subtract or add 26, I forget which, to the numbers (all but the first element) and convert back.

Comment: @TheGreatCO, I'm getting closer, but still not there. Updating post, thanks again!

Comment: might be easier to convert everything to lower and then convert all letters following non-letters to uppercase ...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thanks for the tip, I'll look into that, although I'm actually interested in understanding regex syntax.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio do you care about matching single letter fields as well as multiletter?  Eg, should "I" match and "IT" but not "It"?

Comment: @BenBolker, It is a sound idea indeed, but I really don't want to disturb the other strings, that are well-capitalized and may include complex things such as acronyms). I just want to deal with the all caps nonsense.

Comment: @TheGreatCO, in many cases, my string contains acronyms of variable length, usually in the end (as "ITR" in the example). It would be great if those would be left untouched, but if that's asking too much, just start-casing the whole element is fine by me.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio try `(^[A-Z]{2,}$|^[A-Z]$)`

Comment: @TheGreatCO, this just grabs elements with one word in all caps. To make things worse, I've just found out elements with accents are being left out, even if they're all caps (i.e., "Á").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of this is a demo example in the package `gsubfn`. You can run it after installing the package with `demo(gsubfn::gsubfn-lower)`.

```
x <- c('One', 'TWO', 'THREE / FOUR', 'ÁÁÁ')
library(gsubfn)
## find indices of vector where there are no lowercase letters 
## (therefore all letters must be uppercase)
idx <- grep("[[:lower:]]", x, invert = TRUE)
## in these indices, run tolower on characters 
## that do not follow a word boundary \\B
x[idx] <- gsubfn("\\B.", tolower, x[idx], perl = TRUE)
# [1] "One"          "Two"          "Three / Four" "Ááá"
```

Both `\B` and `[:lower:]` are locale-dependent by `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")`. Mine is `"English_United States.1252"`. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Excellent.  Never reinvent what can be looked up :-)

Comment: FWIW, on my system the last string comes out to `"ááá"`.  Might be delicate/depend on locale.

Comment: @BenBolker Good point. In `?regex` regarding `\b` and `\B`: "(The interpretation of ‘word’ depends on the locale and implementation.)" I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: I've tested it in both `English_United States.1252` and `Portuguese_Brazil.1252`, all is well. Looks good enough for me, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know R so well, but I base this answer in the description of `gsub` and regular expression support given [in this document](http://www3.nd.edu/~sjones20/JonesUND/BioStats_files/RstringManipulation_2-6-13.pdf)

```
gsub("([A-Z])([:alpha:]*)", paste(\1,tolower(\2),sep=""), x)
```

I am not sure if you have to enclose \1 and \2 with quotes, try it and if it does not work try it with the quotes around \1 and \2

Comment: You could at least have tried executing the line before posting. So far as I can tell it's not even selecting what we need.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft As I said, I don't use R. I looked up the documentation. The post creator wanted to set the first letter of each string to uppercase and the rest to lowercase. Who are "we"? Do you know regular expressions? How does it not match the first letter and separate the rest? So far as I can tell you are quick to judge.

Comment: For one thing, you can't (so far as I know) embed an `R` function in a pattern string.  IMHO it's not helpful to post code in the style of one language (assuming there *is* a language which allows preprocessing commands inside a regexp string) as a solution to some other language.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Just trying to help the OP. You are the R-evangelist, so you know better. If you are talking about the [:alpha] group, there are many R examples using those groups, including the linked document I provided. As about using groups, the linked document does list them as part of the R regex capabilities. And last, but not least important, I disclosed first in my answer that I don't know R so well, I do know (very well) regular expressions; and the OP problem is a trivial one for regex. So sorry for trying to help, won't do it next time (or maybe yes, I will decide on the spot) :-)